# Is it necessary to have a using block if you explicitly dispose of a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been getting a `Win32Exception` with that infamous error: `Error creating window handle.` But up until recently, I realized it was happening on a line that tries to call `Environment.Exit(0)` which I subsequently got rid of, and just let the form close itself.

So my question is, whenever I know I'm not going to need a Form anymore, I always call `base.Close()` and `base.Dispose(true)`. If I do that, is it really necessary to put the form inside a `using` block?

Answer (score 3):

It is not really necessary. However, the using block is a handy and fail-safe programming construct. ie. It is common to forget adding the call to dispose. When you choose the 'using' block you never need to worry about disposing the object. So, Its better to practice using the 'using' block for all disposable objects.

You didn't mention about where you placed the call to Dispose method. It should be always in the finally block as explained below.

```
DisposableClass disposableObj = null;
try
{
    disposableObj = new DisposableClass();
    ....
    ....
}
finally
{
    if( disposableObj != null)
    {
       disposableObj.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The same above code can be simplified as

```
using(DisposableClass disposableObj = new DisposableClass())
{
  .....
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Without using a `using`, if your code throws an exception for any reason before reaching your explicit `Dispose` call, your object will not get disposed.

Comment: Wrong. `using` is a recommended approach, but it is nothing more than a syntactic sugar, so `using` itself is not nesessary in any situation. If one can call `Dispose` manually in a proper way, there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Diligent The only other exception-safe "proper way" is to dispose in a finally block, and in most cases `using` is more preferable to _that_.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. It is basically gives you clearer and concise syntax. Internally, using creates a try..catch..finally block ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)), which you can replicate if you want i.e.

```
SomeClass obj = null;
try
{
    obj = new SomeClass();
    obj.SomeOperation();
}
catch()
{
}
finally
{
    if(obj != null)
        obj.Dispose();
}
```

Not sure if there is some need to do that, but why would you do that if you can do it with single using statemenet.

Answer (score 0):

It is *not* necessary to call `Dispose()` on an object encapsulated in a `using` block.  However, with respect to your question, it is good practice to encapsulate disposable objects in `using` blocks, as it ensures that the `Dispose()` method on that object always gets called.

In any case, this code:

```
using (var disposableObject = new DisposableObject())
{
    // Perform some action...
}
```

is *in practice* equivalent to:

```
try
{
    var disposableObject = new DisposableObject();
    // Perform some action...
}
finally { disposableObject.Dispose(); }
```

This is because internally, the `using` block will always call `Dispose()` on your object.  Actually, as a requirement to implementing the `using` statement, your object of choice *must* implement `IDisposable` in order to even compile.

Adding an additional `Dispose()` call at the end of a `using` block is unnecessary and redundant.